# How can I detect several keypresses in C GTK?

Tags: c, events, gtk, signals

I'm writing a GTK based chat and want to implement the following:

In a GtkTextView when hitting Enter a message is sent, but hitting Shift+Enter types a new line.

I just can't figure out how to detect the multiple key press. I can detect just one key with 
GdkEventKey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peek inside the state member of e GdkEventKey , it holds a [bitmask](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkModifierType) of which of modifier keys (shift/control/alt and others) that are also pressed.

In the general case of detecting several keys being pressed, you have to keep track of the pressed keys yourself, i.e. on a key pressed event, you remember that the key is pressed, and on a key released event you forget the key.

Comment: Link is broken. Correct link: http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkModifierType   Cannot edit it myself due to the 6-char minimum edit rule.